# Understanding an x86 ASM function in C

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm currently working through the pintos project and had a question about some assembly macros the project has included

```
#define syscall1(NUMBER, ARG0)                                           \
({                                                               \
  int retval;                                                    \
  asm volatile                                                   \
    ("pushl %[arg0]; pushl %[number]; int $0x30; addl $8, %%esp" \
       : "=a" (retval)                                           \
       : [number] "i" (NUMBER),                                  \
         [arg0] "g" (ARG0)                                       \
       : "memory");                                              \
  retval;                                                        \
})
```

This macro is called to set up the stack for a syscall with only one argument. We push the one argument, the syscall number and trap to kernel. We only pass NUMBER and ARG0, I was wondering where the [number] and [arg0] (lowercase) come from. I have read some docs but didnt find answers. Would love some help!

Thanks

Comment: The docs are [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). You can find similar syntax after the paragraph starting with *"The following i386 example uses the asmSymbolicName syntax"*

Comment: `[arg0]` and `[number]` are just user defined names given by the programmer (they are aliases). That same name is use to substitute into the extended assembly itself. The names can be any identifier you choose. Without them the extended inline assembly would have appeared as `"pushl %1; pushl %0; int $0x30; addl $8, %%esp`  . Rather than using a positional value like `%0` and `%1` the names make the code more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

In GCC’s extended assembly syntax, the notation **[***name***] "***constraints***" (***expression***)** says:

- Make *expression* available to the assembly code.
- Put the *expression* in a place satisfying the *constraints*. The *constraints* describe acceptable places to use, such as general processor registers, floating-point registers, and memory. They may also include symbols telling GCC that the expression will be changed by the assembly code or both read and changed. (For output operands, the expression should be an lvalue so that it provides a place for the new value to be written.)
- Use *name* as the name of the place. Then, when GCC sees **%[***name***]** in the assembly code, it replaces that with the assembly expression that refers to the place, such as `%rax` or `16(r3)`. The **[***name***]** part of the operand notation is optional. If you do not give it, GCC gives the operands names of 0, 1, 2,…, so the assembly code would refer to them with **%0**, **%1**, **%2**,...

Answer (score 1):

The part enclosed in square brackets is a symbolic name used in the ASM tempate only.  The part in the parentheses is the reference to the variable name in your C program.  (More detailed description below)

From the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) for the ASM template:

> ```
> [ [asmSymbolicName] ] constraint (cvariablename)
> ```
>
> - asmSymbolicName
>
>   Specifies a symbolic name for the operand. Reference the name in the assembler template by enclosing it in square brackets (i.e. ‘%[Value]’). The scope of the name is the asm statement that contains the definition.* ***Any valid C variable name is acceptable, including names already defined in the surrounding code.*** *No two operands within the same asm statement can use the same symbolic name.
>
>   When not using an `asmSymbolicName`, use the (zero-based) position of the operand in the list of operands in the assembler template. For example if there are three output operands, use ‘%0’ in the template to refer to the first, ‘%1’ for the second, and ‘%2’ for the third.
> - constraint
>
>   A string constant specifying constraints on the placement of the operand; See Constraints, for details.
>     Output constraints must begin with either ‘=’ (a variable overwriting an existing value) or ‘+’ (when reading and writing). When using ‘=’, do not assume the location contains the existing value on entry to the asm, except when the operand is tied to an input; see Input Operands.
>
>   After the prefix, there must be one or more additional constraints (see Constraints) that describe where the value resides. Common constraints include ‘r’ for register and ‘m’ for memory. When you list more than one possible location (for example, "=rm"), the compiler chooses the most efficient one based on the current context. If you list as many alternates as the asm statement allows, you permit the optimizers to produce the best possible code. If you must use a specific register, but your Machine Constraints do not provide sufficient control to select the specific register you want, local register variables may provide a solution (see Local Register Variables).
> - cvariablename
>
>   Specifies a C lvalue expression to hold the output, typically a variable name. The enclosing parentheses are a required part of the syntax.*
>
> ...

[Extended Asm - Assembler Instructions with C Expression Operands](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)